# Crawler of pictures in php

Tags: php, web-crawler

The question is how to get ajax calls source code? this is not crawled, for example how to crawl the pictures on a link like this? http://www.tiendeo.nl/Catalogi/amsterdam/16558&subori=web_sliders&buscar=Boni&sw=1366

If you do inspect element, then it will show you the right code in the middle where the pictures are. But how to crawl this? If you click the next page, then it will have other images in the source. How to get the source for all images?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (How do I crawl information loaded into the page by ajax calls?), the answer is that you either need some sort of javascript-aware crawler, or you need to inspect the javascript to figure out what resources are being polled to load the content you're interested in. From PHP you should be able to send curl get requests to these URLs and receive the same responses the site's javascript is using to render the entries.

The latter option has some rewards--namely that you will most likely be able to get simple, easy-to-use JSON responses to your requests.

As with most web scraping efforts, it tends to be the case that some content providers won't appreciate your interest in their data (especially if you're collecting it in ways that put undue strain on their systems or resources.) Keep in mind that they make take steps (technical or legal) to stop you if they notice/mind.

**Addendum**: 
If you're hoping to crawl a variety of similar sites *without* needing to look through the source to find the resources they're using, (let's say for the sake of argument that you're just trying to naively scrape all images over a certain size from several sites selling the same sort of items), you'd need the former option--some sort of javascript-aware scraper. I don't know if such a thing exists, but it wouldn't surprise me.